# How to remove unnecessary columns from a imported Table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am importing data from a URL using `=IMPORTHTML` function. But it returns 8 columns I don't need and I want to remove those columns.

I tried the following formula

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTMTL("URL","TABLE",1),"SELECT Col1,Col2")
```

But as expected I got Column 1 and Column 2 as a return.

I want to get the column 1 and avoid next 7 columns and get the other columns after that.

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `"select Col1, Col9, Col10"` and so on? Like, variable amount of columns or so? 'cause otherwise I think your formula is good, you just need to specify the column numbers you want to retain...

Comment: thing is it has 43 columns. I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this without giving individual column names.

Answer (score 0):

From a comment posted by the OP

> thing is it has 43 columns. I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this without giving individual column names.

Yes, there is, use the an ARRAY FORMULA. Example:

```
=ArrayFormula("SELECT COL1, "&JOIN(", ","Col"&Column(I1:AQ1)))
```

Returns

`SELECT COL1, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29, Col30, Col31, Col32, Col33, Col34, Col35, Col36, Col37, Col38, Col39, Col40, Col41, Col42, Col43`